# ASPX: PageMethodes is not always called after upgrade to IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

The app works fine in IE8.
When I upgraded to IE9, the problem appeared.
The code is not changed.

In the javascript there is a function which calls a server side subroutine with parameter.
The problem is: Sometimes the subroutine is performed, sometimes not, even the parameter/data is the same.

What I have done is:

- Add the site as a trusted side in Internet Options/Security
- Add this in the header of the aspx file.: `< meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`

but it doesn't work, same problem: sometimes it works, sometimes not.

Here is the javascript in aspx file:

```js
function IsOK() 
{
//alert("in isOK.")

var erro = '';
var MasterID = document.getElementById('<%= hid_masterID.ClientID %>').value;
var IID = document.getElementById('<%= hid_ID.ClientID %>').value;
var PostID = document.getElementById('<%= ddlGemeente.ClientID %>').value;  
var FunctieID = document.getElementById('<%= ddlFunction.ClientID %>').value;
var StatusID = document.getElementById('<%= ddlNewStatus.ClientID %>').value;
var ResultaatID = document.getElementById('<%= ddlResultaat.ClientID %>').value;
//alert("now goes to server side.")
PageMethods.saveData(MasterID, IID, PostID, FunctieID, StatusID, ResultaatID);
}
```

In aspx I have ScriptManager like this:

```html
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="tsmanager" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"   EnablePageMethods="True"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

In the server side (aspx.vb):

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub saveData(ByVal MasterID As Integer, ByVal IID As Integer, ByVal PostID As Integer, ByVal FunctieID As Integer, ByVal StatusID As Integer, ByVal ResultaatID As Integer)
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("strConn"))

    saveLogfile(MasterID, IID, Usernaam, "In saveData serverside (solldetail_wijzigen.aspx) geraakt op: " + Date.Now().ToString())

    cn = conn
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "uspSoll_SollDetailUpdate"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MasterID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MasterID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@IID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PostID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PostID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FunctieID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FunctieID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StatusID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = StatusID
    If ResultaatID = 1 Then
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ResultaatID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ResultaatID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ResultaatID
    End If
    cn.Open()
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        saveLogfile(MasterID, IID, Usernaam, ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

I have searched for this bug for 2 days, but I could not solve it.
Can anybody please let me why sometime works, sometime not.

Thanks in advance.
Juliando

Comment: Can anybody help me please.

Comment: Can anybody help me please? Someone who has experiences with PageMethods?